# The good method for full text search on one column may contain multi languages?

Tags: postgresql, full-text-search

when I only have english. I use such way.

1. add a new english_column to store tsvector.
2. create gin index on the english_column.
3. create trigger on insert or update.

However. When I want to support other language. This method need create 3 new column.
And query the pattern for 3 different language like

```
select * from where 
   english_column @@ to_tsquery('english', pattern) or 
   german_column  @@ to_tsquery('german', pattern)
```

Can I keep only one new index column to support multi language?

something change like this

```
CREATE TEXT SEARCH DICTIONARY multi_stem_nostop (
    Template = snowball
  , Language = english, german, spanish
);

CREATE TEXT SEARCH CONFIGURATION public.multi_nostop ( COPY = pg_catalog.english, pg_catalog.german );
```

Or I got misunderstanding for the dictionary?

Comment: Why not just add a "language" column?

Comment: You mean detect the language of the pattern and only search on such the special rows match the language?

Comment: Instead of `english_column` just have, `content` and `language` then use the value of the `language` column when calling `to_tsquery()`

Comment: What do you want it to do?  Do you want to stem it in all of those languages, then take the union of the stemmed results?